# SQL Query passing values from Java

Tags: java

I would like to know if when I place a sql query using java , does it retain the new lines?

for instance if i have

```
"IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE EMPLOYEEID='"+EMPID+"')"+
"UPDATE myTable SET ....)"
```

So after the "+" sign in the first line the UPDATE follows, does it maintain the new line when it is being passed to the database?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

No. For the query to work successfully you will have to add a space before UPDATE or after ).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there is no newline in the example source code to "maintain" ...

Secondly, your problem is with Java rather than SQL.  You will only get an newline into a Java String if you put it there explicitly; e.g.

```
// No newline in this string
String s = "a" + 
    "b";

// Line break in these strings
String s = "a" + "\n" + "b";
String s2 = "a\nb";
String s3 = "a" + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "b";
```

Finally, in your example, a space or TAB will do just as well as a line break.